# Problem running a Powershell script in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, powershell

I have the following code to run a Powershell script in vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' create Powershell runspace
    Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()

    ' open it
    MyRunSpace.Open()

    ' create a pipeline and feed it the script text
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()

    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Get-ADGroupMember -Identity ""EDL_ProEquities Smarsh"" -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties Mail | Select-Object Name,Mail,UserPrincipalName | Export-CSV -Path  "“\\pesfs\PESSHARE\technology\1.Smarsh\Archiving Test\EDL_ProEquities\EDL.csv”" -NoTypeInformation")

    ' execute the script
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()

    ' close the runspace
    MyRunSpace.Close()

End Sub
```

It errors out with:
Additional information: The term 'Get-ADGroupMember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

My goal is to export the data generated from the script in to a .csv file and import that into my SQL table. My ultimate goal would be to somehow be able to click a button in my app and have it pull the information generated by the script and import it into the SQL table without having to export to .csv and then importing it. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is the ActiveDirectory module installed on the machine the script is running on?

Comment: The script runs fine from within Powershell on the pc. I assume that means the AD module is installed?

Comment: You might add Import-Module ActiveDirectory; to the beginning of the script.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I tried that and get the same error.

Comment: Importing the module at the beginning of the script worked for me: `MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript("Import-Module ActiveDirectory; Get-ADGroupMember -Identity ......`

Comment: Do you know what else I may be missing? This is on my Windows 10 pc.